# boost proto vs c# expression tree

Tags: c#, c++, boost

First, I'm wondering if both "feature" have the same goal.
Secondly, if yes (or only partially yes), is there any  significant limitation in boost proto over 
c# expression tree

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of Boost.Proto, and I only recently discovered C# expression trees. AFAICT, they are similar in intent, but different both in implementation and scope.

C# has language support for capturing a LINQ expression as a dynamically typed tree. This is used by LINQ consumers to optimize the evaluation of queries. A query against an in-memory data structure would be a straightforward evaluation via the LINQ extension methods, but one against a remote database would be more optimally executed by walking the LINQ expression at runtime, computing a T-SQL string, and passing it to the SQL server for remote execution. As it currently stands, C# expression trees are best at these kinds of optimization problems.

Boost.Proto OTOH has a somewhat broader scope. Proto expression trees are statically typed, allowing complex transformations and code generation to be done at compile-time. More importantly, Proto provides tools for introspecting and transforming trees, and generating custom code from them. That could be useful for optimization, but also for giving expressions completely different domain-specific semantics. So Proto is more accurately thought of as an embedded domain-specific language toolkit.

The same could be done with C# expression trees, but AFAIK there currently exists no framework for tree transformation and code generation. The ability to do runtime code generation on .NET makes this a compelling possibility. Maybe some enterprising developer (you?) would be willing to write a Proto# on top of C# expression trees. :-)

Answer (score 1):

They partially overlap in that they could both be used to write a DSL.  Boost proto is built around the idea of building an embedded DSL in C++ that is transformed to C++ and compiled at compile time. C# expression trees would be more about writing an external DSL(or any interpreter really).  So boost::Proto is about modifying and enhancing C++, and expression trees are about writing code in a new language, not modifying C#.

Answer (score -2):

What actually you wanted to ask ? I do not understand your question.

Their goals are not the same, because C++ and CLR are very different.

In C++ you cannot take arbitrary code and work with it as Expression. You don't have Reflection mechanism.

Expression is RunTime feature while Boost Proto is compile time library.

Comment: Ok so there is really no point in common between proto and c# expression, this kind of affirmation can indeed partially answer to my question